# ¿Cómo teletransportar un auto?

Tags: javascript, unity3d

[image: Imagen1]
[image: Imagen2]
[image: Imagen3]
[image: Imagen4]
Quiero teletransportar un auto e intento usar el típico script de teletransportación, que seria este:

```
var TeleportEndPoint : Transform; //drag your  point to here in the Inspector 

// var spawnPoint : Vector3 = Vector3(0, 10, 0);

function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        other.transform.position = TeleportEndPoint.position;
        // other.transform.position = spawnPoint; // fixed vector method
    }
}
```

Sigo todos los pasos pero cuando paso con el auto que tiene el tag de `player`, no se transporta. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: estate atento de las respuestas y de los comentarios de los que tratan de ayudarte. A ver si logras resolver tu problema. Y nos vas comentando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo arregle con este script:

```
var target : Transform;

function Update () {

}

function OnTriggerEnter (col : Collider) {

    if(col.gameObject.tag == "teleport") {
        this.transform.position = target.position;
    }
}
```

Cualquier pregunta escríbanme.

Answer (score 5):

Agrega un `Rigidbody` a la entrada, sin `Rigidbody` no hay colisiones :)

Si marcas la opcion `isKinematic` a true, el objeto no se moverá aunque choque con tu auto.

Comment: Probaste lo que yo puse?

Comment: No lo probe, porque lo arregle usando otro script. Si te interesa te lo paso. Igual por curiosidad voy a probar lo que dijiste

Comment: Dinos como te fue @JosecitoBaneador para que pueda asignar la puntuación a la buena respuesta.

Comment: @JosecitoBaneador no es por mi sino para otros usuarios que posiblemente tengan el mismo problema que tu :)

Comment: Josecito Baneador puedes probar lo que te comenta @cjf93 y decir algo al respecto para que sepamos si eso soluciona o no el problema? Si eres tan amable de probar para saber quien dio la buena respuesta.

Comment: Posiblemete tambien te ayude con la nueva pregunta que posteaste @JosecitoBaneador, porque sigues teniendo el problema con las collisions

Comment: @cjf93 no sabemos si tu respuesta es la buena, para Josecito. Y quedan pocos días para el bonus +50. Te subí un punto a tu respuesta, porque sabemos que la otra respuesta no le funcionó, lo comenta él mismo. Si no hay más respuestas como los puntos se auto asignan si nos lo asigno yo, te los daré a ti que parece que lo has probado y te funciona.

Comment: @Marc Lemien veamos que pasa al final, el problema es que el solucionó su problema tirando por otro lado. Gracias por el apoyo :)

Comment: Pues basta con que lo comente, para que todo funcione bien aquí en SOes. Posteó un duplicado de esta pregunta, por lo que me dio a imaginar que en realidad seguía teniendo el problema.

Comment: Gracias por todo, estuve de viaje por eso no respondí. No logre probarlo pero use este script                                                                            var target : Transform;
 
function Update () {
 
}
 
function OnTriggerEnter (col : Collider) {
 
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "teleport") {
        this.transform.position = target.position;
    }
}

Comment: @JosecitoBaneador Si tu solución funcionó, deberías publicarlo como respuesta a tu propia pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

El objeto donde se produce la colisión para comenzar la teletransportación, ¿tiene un collider, verdad? Aségurate de tildar la opción `Is Trigger` en la parte del collider en el `Inspector` si quieres que se llame a la función `OnTriggerEnter`.

Comment: Eso lo hice pero de todas formas no sirve, no puedo encontar la manera. Tenes otra idea de que puede ser?

Comment: El auto tiene el tag "Player" y no "player", ¿verdad? los tags en Unity son sensibles a las mayúsculas.

Comment: Correcto tiene el tag Player. Existe algúna otra cosa que se te ocurra.

Comment: ¿El objeto al que le añades el script tiene un Collider con IsTrigger activado? Sé que ya dije esto, pero a veces pasa que metemos varios cuerpos para hacer un objeto, agrupados dentro de un empty object y luego al añadir al mismo el script, nada funciona, porque a veces los objetos padre no tienen las mismas propiedades, en este caso, el collider.

Comment: Por supuesto, me fije justamente eso. Es que ademas probé con otros scripts no tengo idea la verdad de como hacerlo. Nunca me funciono y no quiero tener que cambiar todo un juego por eso.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar una captura de pantalla de tus entidades a la pregunta?

Comment: Ahí subi las fotos a la pregunta, donde muestran el auto la entrada y salida del teleporter y que sucede cuando juego y me meto en la entrada.

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que haya un asunto con las colisiones discretas y el Box Collider de la entrada, prueba editar ese Collider y hacerlo más grande que el cubo visible, sino deberíamos empezar a hacer un debug con el logger.

Comment: No funciono. Voy a escribir otros scripts haber si alguno funciona.

Comment: @JosecitoBaneador prueba lo que te dijo cjf93 antes de hacer tus scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Una alternativa seria usando `OnCollisionEnter`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TeleportEndPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            col.gameObject.transform.position = TeleportEndPoint.position;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A ver si tienes suerte y el que preguntó despierta de su letargo.

Comment: Lo arregle con el script que comente arriba